# Need to return a string as permalink insted of str_replace

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, slug

I'm using this code to get a alphabetic list of CPT's at my site. It's great and works perfect.

One problem, the snippet returns urls as a string, tha just converts the_title to a slug, and that does NOT work when the title contains special characters. I simple need a solution of how to return the_permalink instead of this title-to-slug hack :)

```
<?php $list = ''; 
$tags = get_terms( 'inspirations-emne' ); 
$groups = array();
if( $tags && is_array( $tags ) ) {
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$first_letter = mb_strtoupper( mb_substr($tag->name,0,1) );
$groups[ $first_letter ][] = $tag;}
if( !empty( $groups ) ) {
foreach( $groups as $letter => $tags ) {
$list .= "\n\t" . '<div id="index-letter"><h2>' . apply_filters( 'the_title', $letter ) .'</h2></div>';
$list .= "\n\t" . '<ul>';
foreach( $tags as $tag ) {
$lower = mb_strtolower($tag->name);
$name = str_replace(' ', ' ', $tag->name);
$naam = str_replace(' ', '-', $lower);
$list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="/inspirations-emne/'.$lower.'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
}}}}else $list .= "\n\t" . '<p>Beklager, men ingen emner blev fundet</p>';print $list;
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Any help to modify this snippet is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) to get the correct URL for a taxonomy term archive.

```
$list .= "\n\t\t" . '<li><a href="'. get_term_link( $tag ) .'">'.$name.'</a></li>';
```